# Too many bind arguments. 5 arguments were provided but the statement needs 4 arguments

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

I get the IllegalArgumentException above when executing the function below. What I don't get is that when I run the debugger, the *values* variable clearly only contains 4 arguments, as it should.

So...

(1) Where does this mysterious fifth argument come from?

(2) How should I approach finding this error?

```
db.update(
    UppdragEntry.TABLE_NAME,
    values,
    selection,
    selectionArgs);
```

Comment: *Selection* contains the following: String selection = "_id"; String[] selectionArgs = {" =" + personId};

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Selection contains the following: String selection = "_id"; String[] selectionArgs = {" =" + personId};

You have a value in `selectionArgs` but no `?` placeholder for it in `selection`.

Change it to

```
String selection = "_id = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "" + personId };
```

The method builds an SQL string. Supplied `ContentValues` are built as `?` placeholder and bind arguments. Additional selection args are also provided as bind arguments and they must be matched with equal number of `?` placeholders.

Comment: I had ? in selectionArgs but in case of string I converted ? into '?' which was a mistake.

Comment: Well, it's much better to add String.valueOf(personId) in selectionArgs.

Comment: You are my God.