# Q: How to update 1 column with same data for different IDs (android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here I have an array of IDs and the update method works only if its 1 ID in the array, but if I put 2-3 it gives me an error..something like: `Too many bind arguments. 4 arguments were provided but the statement needs 2 arguments` How can I make it work. I want to set the same value in the same column for different IDs.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DataEntry.COLUMN_DATA, "1");
    String selection = DataEntry._ID + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = selectedData.toArray(new String[selectedData.size()]);
    // To be a bit more clear the above line looks like this:
    // String[] selectionArgs = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; String array of IDs which varies 

    int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, selection, selectionArgs);
```

The update method is as follows:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsUpdated = db.update(DataEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many bind arguments. 5 arguments were provided but the statement needs 4 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797635/too-many-bind-arguments-5-arguments-were-provided-but-the-statement-needs-4-arg)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I'm having an `array` of IDs to be updated and the gentleman has only 1 ID

Comment: Please whoever downvoted(s) to give the reason why... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you could use :-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DataEntry.COLUMN_DATA, "1");
String selection = DataEntry._ID + "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = selectedData.toArray(new String[selectedData.size()]);
for each(String s: selectionArgs) {
    int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, selection, new String[]{s});
}
```

Alternately you could use `WHERE IN (list of id's)` which could be along the lines of :-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DataEntry.COLUMN_DATA, "1");
String selection " IN (?)";
String[] selectionArgs = selectedData.toArray(new String[selectedData.size()]);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < selectionArgs.length(); i++) {
    sb.append(selectionArgs[i]);
    if (i < (selectionArgs.length - 1)) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
}        
int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, selection, new String[]{sb.toString()});
```

Of course you could loop through applying x placeholders. This would be along the lines of :-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(DataEntry.COLUMN_DATA, "1");
String[] selectionArgs = selectedData.toArray(new String[selectedData.size()]);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("IN (");
for (int i=0; i < selectionArgs.length(); i++) {
    if (i < (selectionArgs.length() - 1) {
        sb.append("?,");
    } else {
        sb.append("?)");
    }
}        
int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(DataEntry.CONTENT_URI, values, sb.toString, selectionArgs);
```

- Note this is in-principle code and has not been tested, so it may contain some errors.

Comment: `String selection =  " IN (?)";` and pass a single string of comma separated ID's as the selection arg so something like `String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{your_comma_spearated_list_of_ids_as_a_single_string};`

Comment: Ok maaan, we are the BEST !! That's called team work!! Here is what you have to answer and I will mark it as perfect answer :))...

        // We move 'selectionArgs' above 'selection' to get the size of the array..
        String[] selectionArgs = selectedData.toArray(new String[selectedData.size()]);

        // Here we check how many IDs there are and accordingly build the 'selection'
        // for every ID in the array we add '?'
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgs.length; i++) {
            sb.append("?");

Comment: if (i < (selectionArgs.length - 1)) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        String selection = DataEntry._ID + " IN (" + sb + ")";
        // finally the 'selection' with 3 IDs looks like this: _id IN (?, ?, ?)

Comment: Half a dozen of one 6 of the other. i.e. you have to loop be it with the placeholders or the with the ID's. What I wrote was the least juggling around of code and less likely to confuse considering *Yes i think it is something like this, but how to construct it??*

Comment: In my case I don't need to select more than 5-6 IDs and append '?' is much less memory than updating the database everytime and you cannot get how many rows were affected.. Its up to you!! You helped me to accomplish what i needed so I will mark it as answered... Thank you again! Still for my question your current answer doesn't work.. :))

Comment: Yeah, that's cool, leave the last snippet and remove the rest as its not working.